# Why page is loaded two times when I use Navigator and SpringViewProvider?

Tags: java, spring, navigation, vaadin

I want to show different pages in the same window tab. I use classes Empty and Empty1. The class Empty is a main page and view Empty1 is loaded into Empty.

The class called Empty:

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI(path = "empty")

public class Empty extends UI {

   @Autowired
   private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

   @Override
   protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
       System.out.println("init Empty");
       final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
       root.setSizeFull();
       setContent(root);

       Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
       navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
       navigator.navigateTo(Empty1.VIEW_NAME);
   }
}
```

and class called Empty1 (view):

```
@SpringView(name = Empty1.VIEW_NAME)
public class Empty1 extends VerticalLayout implements View {
   public static final String VIEW_NAME = "empty1";

   @PostConstruct
   void init() {
       addComponent(new Label("This is the default view"));
       System.out.println("init Empty1");
   }

   @Override
   public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
       // the view is constructed in the init() method()
   }
}
```

When I open new window I see sentence "This is the default view" and it's ok. **But when I looked in trackstace I noticed sentence "init Empty1" that is shown two times, why?**

It means that content of view Empty1 is loaded two times. **I want to the view had been loaded only one time.**

The final effect is supposed to look something like this in the 'Empty' class:

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI(path = "empty")

public class Empty extends UI {

@Autowired
private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    System.out.println("init Empty");
    final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
    root.setSizeFull();
    setContent(root);

    Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
    navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);

    int optionAuto = 2;

    switch (optionAuto) {
            case 1:
                getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(Empty1.VIEW_NAME);
                break;
            case 2:
                getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(Empty2.VIEW_NAME);
                break;
           }
    }
}
```

And It works but view 'Empty1' or 'Empty2' are called two times. How can I modifying the code in order to the view was called only one time?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it happens is because you call `Navigator.navigateTo()` in your `Empty.init()` method. Every navigation action creates new view bean instance (views are not singletons). After you call `Navigator.navigateTo()`, it's later called again in `UI.doInit()` method, which results in second bean creation.

If you want to make your "empty1" view a default view (the one which shows up if no other view is specified in url), then something like this should work:

```
if ("".equals(navigator.getState())) {
    getPage().setUriFragment("!" + Empty1.VIEW_NAME, false);
}
```

Of course you can also name the view as `""` to make it default.

Comment: I added the fragment code that you suggested at the end of 'Empty' class. And I commented navigator.navigateTo(...) line, but It doesn't work. A description of this problem is following:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to navigate to an unknown state '' and an error view provider not present path : /empty

Comment: I little edited my question and maybe now I explained better what I want to do.

Comment: I've updated the code, it should work now (it worked for me with vaadin 8.0.5).

Comment: I have other question related with Navigator. What cause this warning: 
WARN  c.v.spring.internal.DefaultViewCache - The Navigator used does not extend SpringNavigator. View scope support may be limited, and future versions of Vaadin Spring may remove support for using a plain Navigator. How can I fix the problem? Is it important this warning?

Comment: @Fisherek15 you should create a new question, this comment section is not a good place to discuss something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you add @UIScope above your class Empty1 then you can use `getNavigator().navigateTo()` without creating a new instance of your view bean every time.